# R create variables from named nested list

Tags: r

I want to create variables based on the key names from a named nested list. The variables contain the corresponding value pair.

Consider the following named nested list:

```
lut <- list(
    parent_a = list(
        key_a = "foo",
        key_b = "bar"
    ),
    parent_b = list(
        key_a = "sna",
        key_b = "fu"
    )
)

# there can only be one parent in my script!
target_parent = "parent_b"

# I want to lift-up the variables so that they are accessible in the global scope as such:
(key_a) # sna
(key_b) # fu
```

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: You can leave them in the list and just operate with the list using `with`. For example `with(lut$parent_b, paste(key_a, key_b))`. Often that's better than clobbering the global environment with temporary variables stored elsewhere. But you can do it if you want with `list2env(lut$parent_b, envir = globalenv())`

Comment: `list2env` ... I would not have guessed that. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

```r
lut <- list(
  parent_a = list(
    key_a = "foo",
    key_b = "bar"
  ),
  parent_b = list(
    key_a = "sna",
    key_b = "fu"
  )
)

new_variable_values <-
  unlist(
    lut$parent_b
  )

new_variable_names <-
  names(
    new_variable_values
  )

purrr::walk2(
  new_variable_names,
  new_variable_values,
  ~ assign(.x, .y, envir = .GlobalEnv)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I go with @mrflick 's comment